# Aligning text with image css

Tags: html, css

There are probably a thousand similar questions, but I've read all I could find and nothing worked for me so far.

I want to align the TEXT, not the image - in a DIV. The text and the image are on the same line.
While experimenting, I've tried to apply different styles to both the image and the text. I cannot wrap the text in a div, because it places each DIV on separate lines. so I've used  a label, and set the style to that.

CSS:

```
.FileFolderStyle {
    background-color: #D9FFD5;
}
.FileFolderImg
{
    width : 32;
    height: 32;
    margin:10px 0px;
}
.FileFolderText
{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="FileFolderStyle">
   <img class="FileFolderImg" src="File.png"/> 
   <label class="FileFolderText">File name </label>
</div>
```

The top part of the "F" of file has to be adjacent to the top part of the image. I've spent literally hours on this minor detail but couldn't find a solution.
Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SxCH2/46/

Screenshot as is:

[image]

Screenshot of desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `inline-block` elements with `vertical-align:top;`.  Should align everything to the top of the containing `<div>`.  Then add the desired `margin-top` as you already have a `10px` margin on your image I guess you want to add that to your `<label>` as well.  You may need to adjust the `line-height` for better control of the text alignment as currently the line-height exceeds the font-size resulting in a little extra white-space at the top and bottom of the text.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/SxCH2/59/

```
.FileFolderImg
{
    width : 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin:10px 0px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    border:1px solid red;
    content:"";
}
.FileFolderText
{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-top:10px;
    line-height:16px;
}​
```

Comment: I think he meant vertical alignment of the text relative to the middle of the image. Or not!

Comment: The JSFiddle puts the Middle of the F with the top of the image, not the top of the F with the top of the image. I'll draw a diagram if you want.

Comment: Trying `margin:0px;` on `FileFolderImg`

Comment: Maybe I don't understand, but the `img` has a top-margin of 10px, so do you want the text aligned to the top of its container or the top of `img`?

Comment: The margin needs to stay there. I posted a screenshot of the desired result. Text top = Image Top + Total Margin

Comment: Hmm... also, if it looks "off" by a couple pixels you need to adjust the `line-height`  I've updated the answer to include that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/SxCH2/57/ You had a margin for the top and bottom which would have made it more difficult to achieve. I've used `display:inline`.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="FileFolderStyle">
   <img class="FileFolderImg" src="File.png"/> 
   <div class="FileFolderText">File name </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Working CSS:

```
.FileFolderStyle {
    background-color: #D9FFD5;
}
.FileFolderImg
{
    width : 32px;
    height: 32px;
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.FileFolderText
{
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    display:inline;
    vertical-align:top;
}​
```